# A question about the dependence of a function on a variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, rational-functions

Suppose that $f_1(x),f_2(x)$, $g_1(y),g_2(y)$ are non-constant *rational* functions and let
$$
F(x,y)=(f_1(x)+g_1(y))(f_2(x)+g_2(y)).
$$
I want to prove that $F$ must depend upon $x$, that is, that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\not\equiv0$.

**My attempt**: Suppose otherwise that $F(x,y)=\phi(y)$, where $\phi$ is some rational function. Note that
$$
\begin{split}
(1)\quad & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(f_2+g_2)+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(f_1+g_1)\equiv0\\\\
(2)\quad & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}(f_2+g_2)+\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}(f_1+g_1)\equiv\phi'(y)\\
\end{split}
$$
that is
$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} \\\\
  \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y} \\
\end{pmatrix}}_{M}
\begin{pmatrix}
  f_2+g_2 \\\\
  f_1+g_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\\\
  \phi'(y) \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Furthermore, by (1)
$$
(3)\qquad\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}\equiv0.
$$
I think that it suffices to prove that $det M\equiv0$, since then, along with (3) we will deduce that $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}\not\equiv0$, a contradiction since $f_1,g_2$ are non-constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expression is only a function of $y$ then so must be
$$f_1(x)f_2(x)+g_2(y)f_1(x)+g_1(y)f_2(x)$$

Hence $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(f_1(x)f_2(x)+g_2(y)f_1(x)+g_1(y)f_2(x)\Big)=0$ which unveils an important relationship: $$-\frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}=\frac{f_2'(x)}{f_1'(x)}$$
Clearly $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}\Big)=0$ and so $$\frac{g_2'(y)}{g_1'(y)}=\frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}$$ But then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}\Big)=0$ which means $$\vec{\nabla}\Big(\frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}\Big)=\vec{0}$$ It follows that $$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}$$ is a constant function. Can you take the wheel from here?

Comment: Thanks @MattBoy for your answer. Is the proof is similar if I want to prove that also $(f_1(x)+g_1(y))(f_2(x,y)+1)$ is depend upon $x$?

Comment: I think your proof is wrong. why $\frac{f_2+g_2}{f_1+g_1}=-\frac{g_2'}{g_2'}$?

Comment: Did you take a closer look at $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(\frac{f_2(x)+g_2(y)}{f_1(x)+g_1(y)}\Big)=0$? Do you know how we got this relationship?

Comment: Yes, it follows since $f_2'/f_1'$ is not a function of $y$. Do $\frac{f_2+g_2}{f_1+g_1}=\frac{g_2'}{g_1'}$ follows from (3) ?